# I want to add unique password for password protected specific page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, password-protection

I'm using the password protected page, using WordPress, visiblity option, password protected. That is a common password. But I have a request form for people to request to view the protected page.

For the request form I'm using "contact form7" Plugin. So that we can send an automatic reply to the users that it's your password.

But I also need the password to expire within a day. When the people need to view the page, after expired password, they have to request a new password.

I have tried the following code to get unique password with expiry time.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'custom_generate_password', 10, 1 );

function custom_generate_password( $contact_form ) {

    // Get the ID of the contact form that triggered the action hook

    $form_id = $contact_form->id();

    // Check if the contact form ID matches the one you want to use

    if ( $form_id == 123 ) { // Replace 123 with the ID of your contact form

        // Get the submitted form data

        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if ( $submission ) {

            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

            // Get the user's email address from the form submission

            $user_email = $posted_data['your-email'];

            // Generate a unique password

            $new_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );

            // Set the expiry time for the password (30 minutes from now)

            $expiry_time = time() + ( 30 * 60 );

            // Save the password and expiry time to the user's session

            session_start();

            $_SESSION['password'] = $new_password;

            $_SESSION['expiry_time'] = $expiry_time;

            // Get the URL of the password-protected page

            $page_url = get_permalink( $page_id );

            // Create the email message

            $to = $user_email;

            $subject = 'Your password for the protected page';

            $message = 'Your password is: ' . $new_password . '\n\n';

            $message .= 'This password will expire at: ' . date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $expiry_time ) . '\n\n';

            $message .= 'To access the protected page, please go to: ' . $page_url;

            // Send the email

            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );

        }

    }

}
```

It's working, I mean it's giving the password with expiry date for each time when I submitted the form.

But the same password is not working on the WordPress protected page.

I also tried many plugins, Password protected, PPWP, WP Members, restricted user access, simple membership, etc. I still didn't get a solution.

Comment: I think you should study more, and forget plugins. My first idea is a separate database table with userId | password | expiryTime and filtering the content, check if posted password is in the table. If yes, return with real content, if not, return with password input text field again or error. Check this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

Comment: The problem you're going to have, is you are generating a new password every time someone submits that form - which means that every user who submits that form will get a different password. However, your protected page has **one** password. Does the content change per user? If not, this is the wrong approach. What you should be doing is generating a new password **for that page**, setting it to that page, and then when a user submits that form, it pulls the password from the DB and sends it. You can have something that regenerates the password for that page instead.

Comment: You are right. Page content won't change. Now if the people request to view the page, the automatic email will generate a unique password which will expire. I don't know how to make the page with this! I mean, now the page is published as public view. Anybody can see it right. I just wanted to be protect, when we enter the password , they could able to view the page. I don't know what to do, so I tried published with password protected. But it gives a separate common password, Can you please help, how can I do this!?

Comment: @Devilmind This is what you want: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174814/automatically-change-page-password - This will change the password of the **page** (you can change the time in the code from that link). Then, the email code you have, you don't generate a new password, you get the **current** password of the page using [$wpdb->get_results()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/)

Comment: Okay. But one thing, I still have doubt. Password will change every 2 days. How the people will get the password!? I mean, people will request to view the protected page. So they will get a unique password with expiry time. Using that password, people can able to view the page. I'm using CF7 for the forms. Here my only doubt is, how people will get the password email.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_password_protect_page() {
global $post;

// Check if the page should be password protected
$password_protect = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_password_protect', true);

if ($password_protect) {
    // Check if the password has expired
    $expiry_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_password_expiry', true);
    if ($expiry_date && strtotime($expiry_date) < time()) {
        $password_protect = false;
    }
}

// If password protection is enabled, display the password form
if ($password_protect) {
    add_filter('the_content', 'custom_password_form');
}
```

}
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_password_protect_page');

function custom_password_form($content) {
global $post;

```
$output = '';
$output .= '<form action="' . esc_url(site_url('wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post')) . '" method="post">';
$output .= '<p>' . __('This page is password-protected. Please enter the password to view its contents.', 'textdomain') . '</p>';
$output .= '<p><label for="password">' . __('Password:', 'textdomain') . '</label><br />';
$output .= '<input type="password" name="post_password" id="password" size="20" /></p>';
$output .= '<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__('Submit', 'textdomain') . '" /></p>';
$output .= '</form>';

return $output;}
```

when you create or edit a page, you'll find two [additional](https://livewallpaperspc.com/) fields:

"Password Protect this Page": Check this box to enable password protection for the page.
"Password Expiry Date": Set the expiry date and time for the password.